# displaing one array multiple times in react

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

when i sent message i want it to display .
but now its displaying same message multiple time like 4/5 times .

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);



socket.on(room, (msg) => {
   setMessages(message=>[...message, msg]);
});
```

```
return (
        <div style={{ "paddingTop": "10px", "backgroundColor": "rgb(85, 85, 85)" }} className="chat-messages">
            {
                messages ? messages.map((message,index) => (
                    <div className="message " key={index}>
                        <p className="meta"> {message.user} <span> {message.time} </span> <span></span></p>
                        <p className="text" style={{ "maxWidth": "80ch", "overflowWrap": "break-word" }}> {message.msg} </p>
                    </div>
                )) : ''
            }
        </div>
    )
```

edit :

i noticed that its socket receiving (room) many times

```
    msgHelpers.addMessage(msgD.room, sm, date).then((id) => {
      console.log("before emit");
      io.emit(id, sm);
    });
```

but in backend its sending just once ...
its printing "before emit" just once .

Comment: I've created a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-tu-oc3tz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Does your code sandbox reproduce the issue?

Comment: i just noticed that problem is with socket io . its reciving 4 times .